# (Python) Pandas - GroupBy() using a similarity function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, cluster-analysis

I'm working with a csv file in Python using Pandas.
I'm having a few troubles thinking on how to achieve the following goal.
What I need to achieve is to group entries using a similarity function.
For example, each group X should contain all entries where each couple in the group differs for at most Y on a certain attribute-column value.

Given this example of CSV:

```html
<pre>
name;sex;city;age
john;male;newyork;20
jack;male;newyork;21
mary;female;losangeles;45
maryanne;female;losangeles;48
eric;male;san francisco;29
jenny;female;boston2;30
mattia;na;BostonDynamics;50
</pre>
```

and considering the age column, with a difference of at most 3 on this value I would get the following groups:

```
A = {john;male;newyork;20
   jack;male;newyork;21}
B={eric;male;san francisco;29
   jenny;female;boston2;30}
C={mary;female;losangeles;45
   maryanne;female;losangeles;48}
D={maryanne;female;losangeles;48
   mattia;na;BostonDynamics;50}
```

Actually this is my work-around but I hope there exists something more pythonic.

```
import pandas as pandas
import numpy as numpy

def main():
    csv_path = "../resources/dataset_string.csv"
    csv_data_frame = pandas.read_csv(csv_path, delimiter=";")
    print("\nOriginal Values:")
    print(csv_data_frame)

    sorted_df = csv_data_frame.sort_values(by=["age", "name"], kind="mergesort")
    print("\nSorted Values by AGE & NAME:")
    print(sorted_df)

    min_age = int(numpy.min(sorted_df["age"]))
    print("\nMin_Age:", min_age)
    max_age = int(numpy.max(sorted_df["age"]))
    print("\nMax_Age:", max_age)

    threshold = 3
    bins = numpy.arange(min_age, max_age, threshold)
    print("Bins:", bins)
    ind = numpy.digitize(sorted_df["age"], bins)
    print(ind)

    print("\n\nClustering by hand:\n")
    current_min = min_age
    for cluster in range(min_age, max_age, threshold):
        next_min = current_min + threshold
        print("<Cluster({})>".format(cluster))
        print(sorted_df[(current_min <= sorted_df["age"]) & (sorted_df["age"] <= next_min)])
        print("</Cluster({})>\n".format(cluster + threshold))
        current_min = next_min


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't do that in pandas. Why don't you just use a clustering algorithm from sklearn, e.g. k-means? Once you have the clustering index calculated by sklearn, you easily groupby on it.

Comment: I have read that I'd need to know the number of clusters and I couldn't think of a way to calculate it because datas could be randomly distributed only in a percentage of clusters. If they were equally distributed (at least once per cluster), I would get math.ceil((max - min)/threshold) clusters. Is it possible to get data correctly inserted in the corresponding cluster with k-means? A little example would be very helpful. I'm going to search about this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

On one attribute this is simple:

1. Sort
2. Linearly scan the data, and whenever the threshold is violated, begin a new group.

While this won't be optimal, it should be better than what you already have, at less cost.

However, in the multivariate case, finding he optimal groups is supposedly NP-hard, so finding the optimal grouping will require brute-force search in exponential time. So you will need to approximate this, either by AGNES (in O(n³)) or by CLINK (usually worse quality, but O(n²)).

As this is fairly expensive, it will not be a simple operator of your data frame.