# pandas: How do I remove duplicate rows by column similarity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I consider a string to be a duplicate line if the difference between the strings is less than one character?

I know how to get the count of differences between strings.
I don't know how to use it in a dataframe.

```
count = sum(1 for a, b in zip(str1, str2) if a != b)
```

I am using the following to process duplicate lines when a character is an exact match
How can I use this to determine if there is a string difference duplication?

```
df = df.groupby("thumbnail_hash", sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
    {
        **columns,
        "pk": "first",
        "affiliate_url": lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()),
        "site": lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()),
    }
)
```

What is the best way to use this in a dataframe column, and groupby?

Input data:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "pk": {0: "1", 1: "2", 2: "3", 3: "1", 4: "3"},
        "thumbnail_hash": {
            0: "3131f3aff6f33303",
            1: "3131f3a7f6f33303",
            2: "edc939781b2e2e0f",
            3: "3131f3aff6f33303",
            4: "edc939781b2e2e0f",
        },
        "affiliate_url": {0: "url1", 1: "url2", 2: "url3", 3: "url1 url2", 4: "url3"},
        "site": {0: "site1", 1: "site2", 2: "site2", 3: "site1 site2", 4: "site2"},
    }
)
```

Comment: Please share sample input and output

Comment: Sample added. Duplicate rows, thumbnail_hash should be first, affiliate_url and site should be combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'd note that your string similarity function is quite idiosyncratic, and you'd likely be better off using something more robust such as [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Secondly, I don't know a fast way to do what you're doing (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45549015/6220759)), but here is something which will work.

First check all of the possible pairs among your unique thumbnail hashes, and return those below a certain distance (you said "less than one character", which I interpreted as "one character or less", otherwise you could just use regular `drop_duplicates`):

```
from itertools import combinations

check_similar = lambda s1, s2: sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b) 
matches = [s for s in combinations(df_.thumbnail_hash.unique(), 2) if check_similar(*s) < 2]
```

Then of the similar matches, just replace one with the other in a loop:

```
for (match1, match2) in matches:
    df_.thumbnail_hash = df_.thumbnail_hash.replace(match1, match2)
```

And then you can just do your regular `drop_duplicates`:

```
df_.groupby("thumbnail_hash", sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "pk": "first",
        "affiliate_url": lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()),
        "site": lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()),
    }
)
```

Comment: I have now tried this with about 200,000 rows of data and found that the `[s for s in combinations(df_.thumbnail_hash.unique(), 2) if check_similar(*s) < 2]` loop takes an inordinate amount of time. How can I improve this?

Comment: I think there are algorithmic ways to speed this up, but it is a difficult problem. You should probably ask it as a separate question.