# python: Looping with itertools.conbinations on a lot of data is very time consuming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

[pandas: How do I remove duplicate rows by column similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483757/pandas-how-do-i-remove-duplicate-rows-by-column-similarity)

In the above question, how do I remove duplicate rows depending on the similarity of the values in the dataframe columns?
and I have completed the process I am looking for, but this code is very time consuming when there is a lot of data and there is no end in sight.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def check_similar(s1, s2):
    return sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b)

matches = [
    s
    for s in combinations(df.thumbnail_hash.unique(), 2)
    if check_similar(*s) <= 5
]

# I thought the check_similar function was the cause, 
# but the following also takes a long time.
matches = [s for s in combinations(df.thumbnail_hash.unique(), 2)]
```

I have no idea how to improve the speed of this. How can I improve the speed?

--- Minimal, Reproducible Example ---

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "pk": {
            0: "1",
            1: "2",
            2: "3",
            3: "4",
            4: "5",
        },
        "thumbnail_hash": {
            0: "3131f3aff6f33303", # <- duplicate
            1: "3131f3a7f6f33314", # <- duplicate
            2: "edc939781b2e2e0f",
            3: "3132f3aff6f33303", # <- duplicate
            4: "0000187aef1f7f7e",
        },
        "affiliate_url": {
            0: "url1 url2",
            1: "url3",
            2: "url4",
            3: "url5",
            4: "url6",
        },
        "site": {
            0: "site1 site2",
            1: "site3",
            2: "site4",
            3: "site5",
            4: "site6",
        },
    }
)

# Get pairs of thumbnail hash differences of 5 characters or less
check_similar = lambda s1, s2: sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b)
matches = [
    s
    for s in combinations(df.thumbnail_hash.unique(), 2)
    if check_similar(*s) <= 5
]

# Then of the similar matches, just replace one with the other in a loop:
for (match1, match2) in matches:
    df.thumbnail_hash = df.thumbnail_hash.replace(match1, match2)

# Since the above process made all duplicates within 5 characters the same value,
# remove duplicate rows in groupby
df = df.groupby("thumbnail_hash", sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "pk": "first",
        "affiliate_url": lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()),
        "site": lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()),
    }
)
```

result:

```
thumbnail_hash     pk   affiliate_url         site
3132f3aff6f33303   1    url1 url2 url3 url5   site1 site2 site3 site5
edc939781b2e2e0f   3    url4                  site4
0000187aef1f7f7e   5    url6                  site6
```

Comment: What's the length of `df.thumbnail_hash.unique()`? If you need to examine each combination and just iterating over each combination takes the bulk of the time then there's not much you can do.

Comment: It will be about 600,000. Is there any way to improve this, such as changing the way the value combinations are looked up?

Comment: That's 179,999,700,000 combinations! You're just trying to determine which rows are considered duplicates using the `check_similar()` metric, correct? The trouble here is what you do with multiple, related duplicates. Consider `check_similar(row1, row2) = 1`, 'check_similar(row2, row3) = 1`, but `check_similar(row1, row3) = 100`. Do you remove rows 2 and 3, or just row2? Once row2 is removed, row3 is no longer a "duplicate." Regardless, my initial feeling is that there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a small amount of test data.

Comment: Yes, the duplicate rows should be identified and deleted except for one duplicate rows. Please see the test data and a reproducible example added to the question.